# Brother MFC-8710 DW no longer displaying an option to print a Word Doc two-sided on a macbook pro running El Capitan.

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, macbook-pro, brother-printer

I installed the update for El Capitan on my MacBook Pro over a month ago, and have had no problems.  Now, suddenly, the option to print a word document as two-sided has disappeared.  I would appreciate it if anyone has a suggestion as to what may be causing this, or how to fix it.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you updated the [drivers](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc8710dw_us&os=10018&dlid=dlf102215_000&flang=4&type3=10062)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I did.  That's what created the problem.